# How to aggregate the microbatch data into a dataframe for spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

The use case is as following. Based on the spark structured streaming, the kafka data is ingested. We hope that the data for each microbatch, every 10 seconds, can be processed and aggregated into a single dataframe, which keeps on monitoring the sum of some values for each id. Is the following way correct? It seems the old data from the previous microbatches are still in the 'monitoring_table' for each query, which causes the unwanted aggregation. What is the best way to solve this issue? Thanks!

````
    val monitoring_stream = df.writeStream
                              .outputMode("append")
                              .format("memory")
                              .queryName("monitoring_table")
                              .start()

      var rounds = 0
      
      while(monitoring_stream.isActive) {
          Thread.sleep(10000)
  
          spark.sql("SELECT * from monitoring_table").show()   
          var tempDF = spark.sql("SELECT * from monitoring_table")
          var batchDF_group = tempDF.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 seconds").groupBy("id").sum("download_volume", "upload_volume").withColumnRenamed("sum(download_volume)","total_download_volume_batch").withColumnRenamed("sum(upload_volume)","total_upload_volume_batch")
          monitoring_df = monitoring_df.join(batchDF_group, monitoring_df("id") === batchDF_group("id"), "left").select(monitoring_df("id"), monitoring_df("total_download_volume"), monitoring_df("upload_volume"), monitoring_df("total_volume"), batchDF_group("total_download_volume_batch"), batchDF_group("total_upload_volume_batch")).na.fill(0)
          monitoring_df = monitoring_df.withColumn("total_upload_volume", monitoring_df("total_upload_volume")+monitoring_df("total_upload_volume_batch"))
          monitoring_df = monitoring_df.withColumn("total_download_volume", monitoring_df("total_download_volume")+monitoring_df("total_download_volume_batch"))
          monitoring_df = monitoring_df.withColumn("total_volume", monitoring_df("total_download_volume")+monitoring_df("total_upload_volume"))                                    

          
          monitoring_df.show()    
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Databricks For some time now, and one of the things that has helped me in Streaming is -

[Databricks Delta Lake](https://databricks.com/product/delta-lake-on-databricks?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=6448987615&utm_offer=delta-lake-on-databricks&utm_content=delta&gclid=CjwKCAjwr7X4BRA4EiwAUXjbt4AvGLb2s_ZUedZQ9zz5brS090hA1YwaNImpAfADy2ZUyfXDtxswWRoCiNMQAvD_BwE)

The feature that makes Databricks Delta Lake relevant here is -
It maintains **“exactly-once”** processing with more than one stream (or concurrent batch jobs).

You may go through the above documentation , and If not databricks delta lake, then you may include some of the functionality from this in your Project.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on Delta Take. It sounds interesting.